# Нет права на чтение файла, хотя я состою в группе владельца файла

Tags: linux, права, chmod

Есть например файл 1.png.

Он принадлежит владельцу и группе `www-data:www-data`.
На файле стоят права `-rw-rw----`

Как я понимаю, просматривать файл может владелец и все кто состоит в группе владельца, т.е. в группе `www-data`.

Мой пользователь `andrey`. 
Я добавил его в группу `www-data` командой `$ sudo usermod -a -G www-data andrey`.
Если просмотреть командой `$ groups andrey`, то в списке группа `www-data` есть.

Но почему-то права на просмотр этого файла всё равно нет. Т.е. я не могу открыть эту картинку в Ubuntu 16.04 в обычном проводнике. 
Почему так происходит? Или я не правильно понимаю механизм прав доступа? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы изменения вступили в силу необходимо перелогиниться.

Comment: Спасибо, а то я уже начал переживать))

Comment: Ну ок, пусть будет комментом. Членство в группах и принадлежность пользователю (а так-же capabilities и многое другое) присваиваются процессу в момент его создания. В обычной ситуации они просто наследуются от процесса родителя, заново-же они устанавливаются только если процесс создаётся в процессе (простите за каламбур) входа в систему (логина). Тогда группы к которым должен принадлежать процесс берутся из файла /etc/groups

Comment: Необязательно. Есть разные способы открытия нового shell с уже обновлёнными данными.